# how to plot on position you want in GUI of scilab

Tags: user-interface, plot, scilab

I wrote a GUI, and I want to plot on the right hand side.

It is not like `subplot(2,2,2)` or something like that, because I want to plot it on right hand side not on the top of right side. Also it is not like `subplot(1,2,2)`.

How to do this?

I can not find any handle of a gcf.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I've improved your english and formatting to be clearer. You may still need to include a [mcve] showing your existing code.

Comment: You need to clarify if you want to define axes on the right hand side of your gui (you can control your layout with 'layout' property ( See the [doc](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.0/en_US/layout.html) ) OR if you already defined axes and you want to plot in the right part of theses axes ( subplot is ok in that case )

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to create `axes` on the right side of the gui or, if you want to subplot thoses axes. The following answer does both.

```
// Lets define a figure with a gridbag layout
fig=figure('layout','gridbag')

// Lets define a frame
frameleft=uicontrol(fig,..
'style','frame',..
'BackgroundColor',[0.2,0.2,0.8],.. // blue so visible
'constraints',createConstraints("gridbag", [1,1,1,1],[1,1],'both','center')) // make it use all the available space

// lets define a right frame : just position it a x = 2, this
// will move frameleft to the left
frameright=uicontrol(fig,..
'style','frame',..
'BackgroundColor',[0.2,0.8,0.2],.. // green
'constraints',createConstraints("gridbag", [2,1,1,1],[1,1],'both','center')) // all the available space from x=2

// then to plot, lets create axes relatives to frameright
a = newaxes(frameright)

// Then all commands works as usual
title('Title')
subplot(1,2,2)
plot2d()
```

produces

[image: fig_screenshot]